# Significato e uso della locuzione "fra sé e sé"

Tags: word-usage, idioms, meaning

Nel romanzo *La testa perduta di Damasceno Monteiro* di Antonio Tabucchi ho letto queste frasi:

> - «L'avvocato gongolò fra sé e sé»
> - «E poi mormorò fra sé e sé: considerazioni cretine»

Mi sono domandata cosa significasse "fra sé e sé" e se si potessero scrivere altre frasi con questa locuzione.

Nel vocabolario [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/se/) ho trovato quest'esempio:

> - Andava ragionando fra sé e sé,

con la spiegazione

> *nell’intimità della propria mente, del proprio spirito*.

Mi piacerebbe però avere più dettagli sul significato e altri esempi di uso di quest'espressione.

Comment: Parlando, gongolando, ragionando come se fosse due o più persone, ma in realtà da solo o comunque senza farlo trasparire a chi è intorno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'idea di *fra sé e sé* è semplice: comportarsi come se si avesse un interlocutore o uno spettatore, ma che questo interlocutore o spettatore sia la stessa persona. Si può essere da soli o in compagnia, in tal caso l'idea è che l'azione o il sentimento non traspaiano all'esterno.

*L'avvocato gongolò tra sé e sé* significa che costui avrebbe voluto [gongolare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gongolare/) ma non potendo farlo, forse perché in presenza di altre persone e dovendo mantenere un contegno, si accontentò di immaginarsi mentre gongolava.

*E poi mormorò tra sé e sé: considerazioni cretine* è di uno che sta ragionando su qualcosa e si scopre a parlare con sé stesso per soppesare le varie possibilità. O forse uno dei presenti ha fatto una considerazione sciocca e il personaggio avrebbe desiderato dire questa sua opinione a qualcuno e, non potendo, la dice a sé stesso.

*Andava ragionando tra sé e sé* mi dà l'idea di qualcuno che è impegnato in un ragionamento che lo prende interamente tanto da apparire fuori dal mondo e in conversazione intima con sé stesso.

Si trova talvolta solo *tra sé*, ma probabilmente non è del tutto corretto.

Answer (score 3):

Si riferisce a quando una persona ragiona nel proprio pensiero su qualcosa, creando una specie di dialogo interno alla propria mente con sé stesso. È un'espressione molto conosciuta, può essere usata tranquillamente anche in un dialogo formale.

> Decise fra sé e sé di affrontare quel problema

è un altro esempio.