# "Tra" e "fra" sono sempre interscambiabili?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions

So che le preposizioni "tra" e "fra" sono in principio equivalenti; ma sono sempre completamente interscambiabili? Per esempio, in questo [post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/2395/707) si è discusso sul significato e l'uso della locuzione "fra sé e sé". Si potrebbe anche dire "tra sé e sé"?

Ci sono differenze regionali o di registro nell'uso di queste preposizioni?

**Aggiornamento:** Ho trovato [questa spiegazione](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fra1/) sul *Vocabolario Treccani*, ma mi sembra un po' difficile di capire e mi piacerebbe avere la vostra interpretazione.

Comment: Lo metto come commento perché spero in una risposta meno personale. Nella mia esperienza gli unici motivi per preferire l'una o l'altra forma sono puramente “estetici”: evitare cacofonie (“tra tre treni”...), cercare o evitare allitterazioni etc.

Comment: Sono intercambiabili, eccetto che nei casi di cacofonia a cui aggiungerei il classico *fra fratelli*.

Answer (score 4):

*Tra* e *fra* sono quasi sempre interscambiabili, e hanno identico significato.

*Tra* e *fra* risalgono a due voci latine semanticamente distinte *intra* e *infra*, ma la differenza è persa già nella Commedia (dove c'è una forte preferenza per *tra*).

La fonte più attendibile è Niccolò Tommaseo (1802-1874) che riporta una serie di esempi in cui cerca di distinguere le due preposizioni. La conclusione è che *tra* e *fra* sono perlopiù interscambiabili, ma per per evitare cacofonie si preferisce talora l'uno o l'altro (*fra* trentatré giorni, *tra* fratelli invece che il contrario). Sebbene

> *tra* noi tre ci s'intende

non sia semanticamente sbagliata, alcuni lo considerano cattivo stile. Si tratta comunque di una scelta soggettiva, difendibile invocando la licenza poetica, dichiarando che la cacofonia (o presunta tale) era deliberata, o addirittura ricordando che Virgilio stesso, durante una passeggiata al limitare di un bosco, disse:

> "Tra tutto l'altro ch'i' t'ho dimostrato".

Answer (score 0):

Secondo me ci sono alcuni contesti in cui potrebbe essere definito "non corretto" l'uso di una piuttosto che dell'altra preposizione, a prescindere dalla gradevolezza dei suoni (es. "fra i frati" o "tra i treni").

Ecco alcuni esempi che mi sono venuti in mente ragionando (ammetto che forse sono soltanto mie preferenze personali...):

> "Tra l'altro". Io non credo sia molto usato "Fra l'altro".
>
> "Tra il dire e il fare"... mi suona scorretto dire "Fra il dire e il fare".
>
> "Fra Milano e Torino" lo userei per evidenziare differenze in generale, mentre "Tra Milano e Torino" lo userei per esempio per la distanza chilometrica o informazioni geografiche: "fra Milano e Torino vi è una grande differenza culturale", "mi trovo ora tra Milano e Torino", "tra Milano e Torino c'è una distanza di 150 chilometri".

Ho poi trovato su internet un interessante approfondimento che riporto qui ([fonte](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=518397)):

*"Fra deriva dal latino “infra”, contrazione di “infera”, che significa “parte inferiore”, cioè ‘sotto’, ‘di sotto’. Dovremmo dire, per fare un esempio, che l’ascensore si è bloccato fra (non tra) il quarto e il quinto piano, cioè “sotto” il quinto piano. Tra, invece, e il latino “intra”, vale a dire “in mezzo”. Secondo queste distinzioni si dovrebbe dire, quindi, “tra amici”, vale a dire “in mezzo” ad amici; non “fra” che etimologicamente starebbe per “sotto gli amici”."*

Infine riporto una risposta ufficiale al quesito posto da un utente all'Accademia della Crusca:

*"Le due preposizioni sono del tutto analoghe, a tal punto che quando
si vuole fare un esempio di sinonimi perfetti si ricorre proprio
all'esempio di tra e fra. L'unico criterio che può indurre a scegliere
l'una piuttosto che l'altra è di tipo fonico: per evitare l'accumulo
di suoni dentali, ad esempio, si può scegliere fra in sequenze del
tipo "un tributo tra tanti" (meglio: "un tributo fra tanti"); d'altro
canto sarà più eufonico tra dove ricorrano più suoni fricativi (com'è
appunto la f), quindi, ad esempio "un frutto tra le fronde" è
decisamente meglio di "un frutto fra le fronde". Ma, come vede, si
tratta di casi "limite", artificialmente inventati per
esemplificazione e sicuramente poco ricorrenti nella lingua reale. In
generale quindi le due preposizioni sono perfettamente
intercambiabili.
Cordiali saluti,
Raffaella Setti
Redazione Consulenza Linguistica Accademia della Crusca"*

Comment: Fra l'altro, mi pare che *tra l'altro* sia cacofonico e meno usato. `;-)` Analogamente, si preferisce *tra il dire e il fare* per evitare la cacofonia.

Comment: Non mi è chiaro il senso dell'“approfondimento” trovato “su internet” (fonte? su internet ovviamente c'è tutto e il contrario di tutto): in italiano “fra” non ha (più) il senso di “sotto”, se no «fra il quarto e il quinto piano» indicherebbe una posizione sotto entrambi i piani, mentre invece vuol dire “sotto il quinto e *sopra* il quarto”... L'etimologia è preziosissima, ma non sempre possiamo riportare di peso all'oggi i significati e gli usi dei termini originari.

Comment: Ecco la fonte (la stessa spiegazione l'ho poi trovata su altri siti): [link](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=518397) Visto che "tra" e "fra" è uno dei pochi casi, pare, di perfetta sinonimia in italiano, ritengo molto interessante la ricerca delle diverse origini delle due preposizioni, per capire se esse abbiamo avuto in passato significati diversi.

Comment: Grazie, Andrea, e vedo che in realtà la fonte originale è [questa](http://faustoraso.ilcannocchiale.it/2008/12/04/tra_e_fra_che_differenza_ve.html). È giustissimo tenere presenti gli etimi ma, come dicevo, non sempre ha molto senso attribuire di peso alle parole italiane il senso delle parole latine o italiane antiche da cui derivano, altrimenti “il” dovrebbe significare “quello”, “donna” dovrebbe significare “padrona”, “cattivo” “prigioniero” e così via.