# Si dice "tra loro" o "tra di loro"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

Ho un dubbio su questa frase: "Ho due figli vivaci che spesso bisticciano tra...". Devo scrivere "loro" oppure "di loro"? In un certo senso mi suonano tutti e due corretti. Posso usare entrambi? Oppure uno è magari più colloquiale dell'altro?

Comment: http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/T/tra.shtml#

Comment: Un rapido esame tra i dizionari dice che vanno dall'ignorare quest'aspetto, ad ammetterlo (come il Sabatini-Coletti menzionato qui sopra o il [De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/tra): «preposta a un pronome personale può essere seguita dalla preposizione di: *parlando tra di noi*, *è il primo tra di loro a essersi laureato*») a sconsigliarlo, come il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tra/): «*sia detto tra noi*, *rimanga tra noi* (meno bene *tra di noi*), di cose dette in confidenza».

Comment: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/3498/tra-e-fra-sono-sempre-interscambiabili?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Sono entrambe corrette ma è piu "udibile" la forma:

> Ho due figli vivaci che spesso bisticciano tra di loro

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @John!

Comment: Che significa “udibile”?

Comment: Meno cacofonico .

Comment: Concordo. Le due forme sono equivalenti, ma "tra di loro" è più orecchiabile ed è anche più usata dagli italiani.

Comment: Che cosa suoni meglio o peggio è del tutto soggettivo (a me suona meglio “tra loro”); quanto al “più usata dagli italiani” sarebbe interessante, se fosse vero, ma a quanto pare [non lo è](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tra+loro%2Ctra+di+loro&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctra%20loro%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctra%20di%20loro%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: mitico @DaG :) Va comunque detto che quella è una ricerca nei libri (presenti in Google), quindi non si tratta di lingua parlata.

Comment: Grazie, @maxadamo. Hai ragione sulla possibile differenza tra scritto e parlato: se ci sono corpora dell'italiano parlato che permettono un confronto tra le due espressioni, consultiamoli. (E a voler essere pignuoli, chi ha posto la domanda chiedeva proprio «Devo scrivere "loro" oppure "di loro"?»)

Comment: Sarebbe interessante, ma impraticabile, svolgere un sondaggio per sapere quale delle due forme è la più usata nel gergo comune.

Answer (score -1):

Penso che "tra di noi" sia molto più bello, oltre che più usato. Non necessariamente dai più giovani, che si sono ormai abituati ai doppiaggi dei film in inglese (between us) e a dire "Non avevo realizzato che" al posto di "Non mi ero reso conto che". Come fonte "autorevole" suggerisco amichevolmente di ascoltare la canzone "Te lo leggo negli occhi", cantata da Dino (1964): "Tra di noi forse nascerà un amore vero, te lo leggo negli occhi, tu lo leggi nei miei".

Comment: alsa, che cosa ti fa pensare che sia più usato? Hai visto [qui](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tra+loro%2Ctra+di+loro&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctra%20loro%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctra%20di%20loro%3B%2Cc0)?

Comment: Se i testi delle canzoni sono un indice di uso delle espressioni linguistiche, allora va considerata anche "Detto tra noi" di Edoardo Bennato, 1972! Credo che scegliere tra le due possibilità sia un fatto di gusto più che di grammatica.